# Tensorflow Lite model predicting the same output with random input

Tags: python, java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have trained a tensorflow neural network on the Fashion MNIST dataset(https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/zalando-research/fashionmnist) in order to recognise different clothing types.

The model works well with reasonable accuracy (~0.89) when training and testing. I then export the model to tensorflow lite (see co-lab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1okFZpFFEfrRnsPx13OB7-6QyGL3NY13h?usp=sharing) . I would like to use the model in an android app using the Firebase ML API. I have uploaded the generated .tflite model to firebase and successfully downloaded it onto my android app:

(For reference bitmap is the image taken directly from a camera activity and passed into a fragment)

```java
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: view created");
        LinearLayout loading = view.findViewById(R.id.loading_overlay);
        ProgressBar pb = view.findViewById(R.id.loading_pgb);

        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pb.animate();


        bitmap = getBitmap(mParam1);

        ImageView capturedImage = view.findViewById(R.id.capturedImageView);
        capturedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        capturedImage.invalidate();

        //creates download conditions for the ML model
        CustomModelDownloadConditions conditions = new CustomModelDownloadConditions.Builder().requireWifi().build();

        //downloads ML model
        FirebaseModelDownloader
                .getInstance()
                .getModel("Clothing_detector", DownloadType.LOCAL_MODEL_UPDATE_IN_BACKGROUND, conditions)
                .addOnSuccessListener(customModel -> {
                    //creates model file
                    File modelFile = customModel.getFile();

                    //checks if file exists:
                    if (modelFile != null){
                        //creates TF interpreter
                        Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(modelFile);

                        //modify image:
                        int dims = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                        //create thumbnail size bitmap
                        bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, dims, dims);

                        //create scaled bitmap with correct input size
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 28, 28, true);

                        //show preview image to user
                        capturedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                        //create byte buffer for input into ML model
                        ByteBuffer input = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(28 * 28).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

                        //iterate through pixels
                        for (int y = 0; y < 28; y++){
                            for (int x = 0; x < 28; x++){
                                int px = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

                                //get channel values:
                                int r = Color.red(px);
                                int g = Color.green(px);
                                int b = Color.blue(px);

                                Log.d(TAG, "Red: " + r + "\nGreen: " + g + "\nBlue: " + b);

                                //Convert rgb into greyscale
                                int pixel = (r+g+b)/3;

                                Log.d(TAG, "pixel: " + pixel);

                                //cast pixel into a byte then add to bytebuffer.
                                byte pix = (byte) pixel;

                                //Log.d(TAG, "Putting: " + pix + " into " + input);
                                input.put(pix);
                            }
                        }

                        //creates output array and runs classification
                        int bufferSize = 10* Float.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;
                        ByteBuffer output = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                        interpreter.run(input, output);

                        //gets the value of the highest probability
                        output.rewind();
                        FloatBuffer probabilities = output.asFloatBuffer();
                        Log.d(TAG, "probabilties: " + probabilities);

                        try{
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getActivity().getAssets().open("class_labels.txt")));
                            HashMap<String, Float> array = new HashMap<>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.capacity(); i++){
                                String label = reader.readLine();
                                float probability = probabilities.get(i);
                                Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s: %1.7f", label, probability));

                                array.put(label, probability);
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "array: " + array);

                            String label = getHighest(array);
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Found: " + label, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Highest: " + label);

                        } catch (IOException e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not find file!");
                        }





                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: Error downloading model: " + e);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                });


    }
```

getBitmap function:

```java
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String uriString){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        Bitmap bitmapImage;
        try {
            bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    return bitmapImage;
    }
```

Here is the problem:

When the image is blank (ie completely black) the output is as follows:

```
2023-08-27 09:22:02.112  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 D  probabilties: java.nio.ByteBufferAsFloatBuffer[pos=0 lim=10 cap=10]
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  T-shirt/top: 0.1622879
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Trouser: 0.0143318
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Pullover: 0.0639048
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Dress: 0.1209892
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Coat: 0.0266046
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Sandal: 0.2039593
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Shirt: 0.2115460
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Trainers: 0.0570524
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Bag: 0.1211368
2023-08-27 09:22:02.113  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Ankle Boots: 0.0181872
```

And thus the model cannot successfully classify the image (as expected) however, when the image is NOT black, the model outputs the following:

```
2023-08-27 09:25:24.927  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Trouser: 0.0000006
2023-08-27 09:25:24.927  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Pullover: 0.0000034
2023-08-27 09:25:24.927  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Dress: 0.0000000
2023-08-27 09:25:24.928  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Coat: 0.0000000
2023-08-27 09:25:24.928  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Sandal: 0.0000044
2023-08-27 09:25:24.928  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Shirt: 0.0004247
2023-08-27 09:25:24.928  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Trainers: 0.0000002
2023-08-27 09:25:24.928  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Bag: 0.9900765
2023-08-27 09:25:24.928  5936-5936  DEBUG TAG               com.REFOVOAPP.refovo                 I  Ankle Boots: 0.0094875
```

And the model predicts the same output (Bag) for every single image (regardless of what it is) with an unreasonable degree of probability.

As others have suggested, I then took the model and imported it into a python program that will test the model by giving it a random input array:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(255* np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.uint8)
#print(input_data)

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

The output of which is as follows (run three times):

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/willi/untitled0.py')
[[2.7504451e-05 5.5880201e-07 7.1274367e-06 2.6180421e-06 9.1017710e-06
  1.7140882e-11 1.4475138e-03 8.0427203e-09 9.9850559e-01 4.5677253e-09]]

runcell(0, 'C:/Users/willi/untitled0.py')
[[5.0418865e-04 6.9088601e-05 2.0312506e-04 3.4583773e-05 1.1388645e-04
  1.8460551e-07 1.5305695e-01 1.8632382e-07 8.4601682e-01 1.0218894e-06]]

runcell(0, 'C:/Users/willi/untitled0.py')
[[3.6724748e-05 8.1009617e-08 2.8073968e-05 4.6335451e-08 3.6914200e-06
  3.7606078e-11 1.1366847e-03 7.9313711e-09 9.9879456e-01 1.5392963e-07]]
```

And therefore it is showing the same behaviour with the random input suggesting there is a problem with the model.

After following other suggestions I have checked the input shape (which looks fine) and the input type (uint-8) which again seems fine (I would expect to see an error if it was not?). The model was trained including a layer to normalise the 0-255 input to 0-1.

I still have a feeling that the input type/shape is the issue but I don't know how to solve this. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: I've ran into a similar situation into which I was running a binary LightGBM model and it would output basically the same probability no matter the input data. In my case, it was a balancing problem (there were so many positive cases that the model was not learning the negative ones). Maybe that's the case here? You have much more bags than other cases in your training data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked the Fashion MNIST dataset and there is an even distribution of classes (ie 6000 images of each class ie bag, t-shirt etc) in the training set and similarly 1000 images of each in the test set (making a total of 70k images, 60k training, 10k test - all with an even distribution).

Comment: please amend the syntax errors in the code so
that other users can reproduce the problem quickly:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, I am not aware of any syntax errors in the code I have shared, however if you could point them out I would happily change them. I have included the full code for the onViewCreated method incase that is what you are referring to.